# How to handle dependent arguments using argparse?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I am trying to configure `argparse` so that only the following argument combinations are valid:

```
--flagA --argument1 val1 --argument2 val2 --argument3 val3
--flagB --argument1 val1
```

So far, I have written the following piece of code however it doesn't do the trick as both `--argument2` and `--argument3` are optional:

```
required_args = arg_parser.add_argument_group()
required_args.add_argument('--argument1', required=True)

# Optional arguments
optional_args = arg_parser.add_argument_group()
optional_args.add_argument('--argument2', required=False)
optional_args.add_argument('--argument3', required=False)

# Flags
flag_group = arg_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
flag_group.add_argument('--flagA', dest='flag', action='store_const', const="flagA")
flag_group.add_argument('--flagB', dest='flag', action='store_const', const="flagB")

args = vars(arg_parser.parse_args())
```

With this setting, `--flagA --argument1 val1` is also but it shouldn't be.

I know that I can process the `Namespace` generated after calling `.parse_args()` and check whether `--argument2` and `--argument3` are provided when `--flagA` is passed however I am looking for a more natural way to achieve this.

Essentially, the definition should look like the one below:

```
[-h] --argument1 ARGUMENT1 (--flagA --argument2 ARGUMENT2 --argument3 ARGUMENT3 | --flagB)
```

Comment: Mutually Exclusive Groups is the only co-occurrence tool in `argparse`.  It's a simple `xor`.  If that doesn't work for you, use the post-parsing testing.  There's nothing 'natural' about trying to use `argparse` for everything.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a subparser for the two flags?

something along the lines of

```
arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparser = arg_parser.add_subparsers(dest="flag", required=True)

flag_a = subparser.add_parser('flagA')
flag_a.add_argument('--argument1', required=True)
flag_a.add_argument('--argument2', required=True)
flag_a.add_argument('--argument3', required=True)

flag_b = subparser.add_parser('flagB')
flag_b.add_argument('--argument1', required=True)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This does not work properly. Even `python myscript.py  --flagB --argument1 val1` does not pass.

Comment: `flagA` and `flagB` aren't options any more: `python myscript.py flagB --argument val1`.

Comment: This version works, but the flags don't have the "`--`" prefix when you call them since that prefix causes the arg parser to identify the argument as a new argument rather than the input for the subcommand. looking for a workaround now.